# Sorting NSMutableArrays alphabetically

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have an NSMutableArray, called categories, which contains an object called CategoryItem. CategoryItem has an NSString property, *text. Now how would I sort this Array based on the text property of the elements? Sorry if this doesn't make sense, I'm new to all this.

I tried this:

```
[categories sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

But it failed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's because you're trying to sort the array based on each object, not on the string it contains.

You need to use an instance of NSSortDescriptor to sort your array. You can create one like this:

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"text" ascending:YES];
```

Then:

```
[categories sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor]];
```

Comment: You might want to use sortDescriptorWithKey:ascending:selector: instead so you can specify the selector as localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:

Comment: Thanks trudycousing, I tried this and it seems to crash my app when I call the sort function. I got this in the console: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<CategoryItem 0x876aa50> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key CategoryItem.'
*** First throw call stack:`

Comment: @Mackey18 See my edit. Got a little froggy with the key string; it suffices only to be "text".

Comment: Just for clarification, you don't compare the array based on each object but using a selector of each object that doesn't exist (yet).

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
[categories sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    CategoryItem object1 = (CategoryItem)obj1;
    CategoryItem object2 = (CategoryItem)obj2;
    return [object1.text compare:object2.text];
}];
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. For some reason, I couldn't get this to work.

Answer (score 4):

It fails because you did not implement localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare for CategoryItem.

If you want to do that, implement that function for CategoryItem like

```
- (NSComparisonResult)localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:(CategoryItem *)anItem
{
    return [anItem.stringProperty localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:self.stringProperty];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You kinda did this right.

The problem being that you're trying to sort strings, but you dont have strings, you have CategoryItems. To keep the same code, you would just implement `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:` for CategoryItem. In that function, compare the text value and return the correct `NSComparisonResult`. Probably something like this

```
-(NSComparisonResult)localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:(CategoryItem *)item2 {
    return [text localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:[item2 text]];
}
```