# Sort an NSMutableArray alphabetically

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray

I have an NSMutableArray with this values:

> how, format, anderson, babilon,

I would like to know if there is a command in which you can arrange this array in alphabetical order, so that the end result of the array becomes this:

> anderson, babilon, format, how

observation -> my example above 4 items are specified in an array, but actually this array can store more than 1000 items, Someone can help me?

Comment: Yes. There is such a command.

Comment: Please read the docs for `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: checkout this answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351182/how-to-sort-a-nsarray-alphabetically

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I sort an NSMutableArray alphabetically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723697/how-can-i-sort-an-nsmutablearray-alphabetically) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315323/how-can-i-sort-strings-in-nsmutablearray-into-alphabetical-order?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498624/sorting-nsmutablearrays-alphabetically?rq=1

Comment: FYI - as you type a question, SO shows you related questions that may already answer your question. Please always check them before submitting your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to know if there is a command in which you can arrange
>   this array in alphabetical order, so that the end result of the array
>   becomes...

**Yes.** If you look at the [`NSMutableArray` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) you'll find a list of methods that can be used for sorting. They all start with the word "sort".

Apple also provides documentation on sorting arrays in the section named [Sorting Arrays](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Arrays.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000132-SW5) in *Collection Programming Topics*. For example, you could use the method `-sortUsingSelector:` this way:

```
NSMutableArray *names = [@[@"how", @"anderson", @"format", @"babilon"] mutableCopy];
[names sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Comment: Your example is slightly confusing because `integerValue` will make all strings equal.

Comment: @MartinR Good point -- I was snoozing. I'll improve my answer directly.